# Creating different rules according to a config_setting

Tags: cross-platform, bazel

### Introduction

I'm implementing a build system for a cross-platform API with a custom build process. For each platform I have a rule that build the target, for example:

```
build_for_linux = rule(...)
build_for_windows = rule(...)
build_for_mac = rule(...)
```

The outputs are not regular executables and each rule has a completely different set of actions to perform. Therefore, combining them all into a generic rule would not make sense (just for comparison, you would never combine the actual building of a `win32`'s `exe` and an androids' `apk` in the same rule).

### The Problem

I need to let the user decide what platform they want the output for. In other words, I need to find a way to call each of these functions according to an input.

### The current (bad) solution

Until now I had a `config.bzl` file that had the platform to build to and then I took this value and called the right rule accordingly:

`config.bzl`:

```
platform_to_build_to = 'Linux'
```

`platform_build.bzl`:

```
platform_rules_dict = {
    'Linux': build_for_linux,
}

def redirect_to_platform_rule(**args):
   build_for_x = platform_rules_dict[platform_to_build_to]
   build_for_x (**args)
```

The problem is that the user would need to edit my private (e.g. created by me) `.bzl` file in order to define her/his platform which make it a bad and not-intuitive solution.

### The question

[`config_setting`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/general.html#config_setting) seems to be a good solution. The problem is that you can only use [`select`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/functions.html#select) when you know which rule you're going to call. Which is not the case in here.

- It there a way of creating a rule according to `config_setting`?
- Am I doing it right? Do you have another idea?

Sorry about the long question, I want to save you some time by answering all of the reader questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're correct, select is used for attributes not rules. You can get behavior like what you want be using the alias rule and applying a select on its "actual" argument.

For example, the following macro creates an alias rule that points to either a py_binary on Mac but a sh_binary on all other platforms

```
def sh_or_py_binary(name, **kwargs):
  native.sh_binary(
      name = name + "_sh",
      **kwargs
  )
  native.py_binary(
      name = name + "_py",
      **kwargs
  )
  native.alias(
      name = name,
      actual = select({
          "@bazel_tools//src:darwin": name + "_py",
          "//conditions:default": name + "_sh",
      }),
  )
```

Note that this approach is simplistic in that we are creating both a sh_binary and a py_binary with the same argument, so the arguments need to be common to both or Bazel's loading phase will fail.